# How to render a form from another django app including error handling

Tags: python, django, forms

on my landing page / home page I want to add a contact form and a subscribe to newsletter form. Since I want to keep the logic for both forms in separate apps I am wondering how I can use Django's internal form error handling in case the user does an input error. Similar to the standard form error handling I want that the landing page is reloaded with the errors next to the form fields. This is fairly easy if the logic stays within the same app but I can't wrap my head around it how to do this when the logic is in another app. Here is the basic layout:

project/views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from contact.forms import ContactForm
from newsletter.forms import NewsletterForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    contact_form = ContactForm()
    newsletter_form = NewsletterForm()
    title = "Home"
```

contact/forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Contact


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['contact_name', 'contact_email', 'content']
        widgets = {
            'contact_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your name'}),
            'contact_email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email address'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your message'}),
        }
```

contact/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    contact_email = models.EmailField()
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_name + self.timestamp
```

contact/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import View

from .forms import ContactForm


class SendContactForm(View):
    form_class = ContactForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("all ok")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
        else:
            print(form.contact_name.errors)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
```

So the question is now how must the contact (or newsletter) view look like and the project view look like to handle errors with Django's normal internal form handling (adding error messages next to the incorrect input fields).

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:
I wanted to share the solution I ended up using. Maybe there is a best practice how to show several forms on the front page but handle the logic in respective apps. However, this ended up working for me.

project/views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from contact.forms import ContactForm
from newsletter.forms import NewsletterForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home2.html"
    title = "Home"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            old_contact_form = self.request.session["contact_form"]
        except:
            old_contact_form = None
        try:
            old_newsletter_form = self.request.session["newsletter_form"]
        except:
            old_newsletter_form = None
        context["contact_form"] = ContactForm(old_contact_form)
        context["newsletter_form"] = ContactForm(newsletter_form)
        return context
```

contact/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import View

from .forms import ContactForm


class SendContactForm(View):
    form_class = ContactForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("all ok")
        else:
            request.session["contact_form"] = request.POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("home"))
```

And the same in the respective newsletter. Using sessions did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This could me one of the solution. If form validation fails send the form back as context

```
if form.is_valid():
   print("all ok")
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
else:
   print(form.contact_name.errors)
   return Render(request, '/path/to/your/tempalate', context={'form': form})
```

You can do something like this to capture error on your template
home.html

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.contact_name.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.contact_name.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.contact_name }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.contact_email.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.contact_email.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.contact_email }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this does not redirect back to home and hence you will have a different URL after sending the form. I would like to have some sort of redirect scheme to stay within previous URL but keep the logic in the other app.